# Regression problem with MLPRegressor (scikit)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I need to develop a neural network able to produce as output values of a 2D map (for example of a gaussian distribution) starting from fewparameter in input (offset, limit, sigma). In the code below I tried to start, probably in the wrong way, with a simpler case study with the 1D map of a gaussian distribution.

Output are not as expected, I don't know if I miss the data formatting or the instance of the neural network. Any sugestion?

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def gaussian(x, alpha, r):
          return 1./(math.sqrt(alpha**math.pi))*np.exp(-alpha*np.power((x - r), 2.))

features = 20000
output = 1000

w = []
j = []
for iii in range(0,features):  
    mu,sigma = 0.,(iii+1)
    x = np.linspace(-(iii+1), (iii+1), output)    
    t = gaussian(x, sigma, iii)
    t = t.tolist()

    dummy = np.zeros(3)   
    dummy[0] = sigma
    dummy[1] = (iii+1)
    dummy[2] = (iii)

    dummy = dummy.tolist()  
    w.append(t)
    j.append(dummy)  


nn = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(5000,10), activation='tanh', solver='lbfgs')

model = nn.fit(j,w)

test_i = [[1.0,1.0,0.0]]
test_o = nn.predict(test_i)
```

Comment: add output and/or error, otherwise no-one knows what you wanna do

Comment: output is a 1 x output array with random number instead of a gaussian 1D distribution over the "output" samples